# Caracteres no se muestran con buena codificación

Tags: python, micropython

Estoy trabajando sobre un microcontrolador que emplea `micropython` y estoy teniendo problema absurdo. A la hora de mostrar/escribir unos resultados que están en binario, no se me muestran correctamente.

A continuación muestro lo que se me escribe en un fichero txt que voy rellenando:

```
Payload: ©@AöðYD)\†D
```

Y esto es lo que se muestra en la consola:

```
Payload: �@A��YD)\�D
```

Según entiendo esto es un problema de codificación. Para ello y teniendo en cuenta que trabajo con `micropython` y que tiene muchas librerías limitadas, he probado a codificar directamente mi `String` de la siguiente manera:

```
str(payload, 'utf-8')
```

Esto no da error pero no soluciona nada. Concretamente el resultado que he mostrado anteriormente es haciendo esto.

También he visto que lo común es emplear `decode()`, por eso hice:

```
payload.decode("utf-8")
```

Pero me da error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

He probado convirtiendo a `string` pero sigo con el mismo error,

```
str(payload).decode("utf-8")
```

Por lo tanto, ¿estoy planteando mal el problema? ¿Cómo podría mostrar correctamente el mensaje?

Por si es importante, este es un conjunto de valores flotantes, que han sido previamente convertidos a byte mediante la librería `struct`.

Añado como se genera ese payload por si hace falta para replicar el problema:

```
import struct

valores = ['12.0048', '871.765', '1074.88', '0']

payload = struct.pack('B', 6)
for val in valores:
  val = struct.pack('f', float(val))
  payload = payload + val
```

Por lo tanto el resultado debería ser algo similar a este hexadecimal: `06 a9 13 40 41 f6 f0 59 44 29 5c 86 44 00 00 00 00`.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Publica el código que podamos copiar-y-pegar para probar. Si no, sería sólo adivinar.

Comment: Parece que tu payload no es utf8. Intenta `str(payload, "cp1252")`

Comment: Pues no, tampoco es ese. ¿Existe alguna librería/lista que contenga TODOS los posibles encodings? De ser así hago un bucle for y veo cual saca lo que quiero...

Comment: He añadido los valores que convierto, cómo lo hago y que debería mostrarse (o similar, pues supongo que quizás haya `\x`).