# Seleccionar un byte de una cadena con valor entre 1 y 255

Tags: python

Estoy teniendo un problema trabajando con cadenas binarias.

Mis cadenas son de la siguiente forma:

```
b'017f014000100000004000004040000080400000a0400000c0400000e040000000410000104100002041000030410000404100005041000060410000004000004040000080400000a0400000c0400000e04000000041000010410000204100003041000040410000504100006041'
```

Donde realmente se divide en tres partes:

- El Primer byte es un identificador del tipo de trama que por ahora puede variar entre 01 y 04.
- El segundo byte es otro identificador, que cómo quiero que sea un único byte va desde 1 (he obviado el cero en mi código) hasta 255. Cuando llega a 256 se resetea a 1.
- El resto de bytes son los datos de trabajo en sí.

Lo que yo hago es que teniendo diferentes parámetros en cuenta cómo la longitud de la trama, la cobertura que tengo en ese momento, etc. Divido la cadena en diferentes subcadenas para poder enviarlas a trozos. PERO SIEMPRE ENVIANDO LOS DOS PRIMEROS BYTES DE IDENTIFICACIÓN. Es decir, realmente solo divido del tercer byte en adelante.

**Aquí viene el problema**

En un momento dado, separo de la trama esos dos primeros bytes, del resto.

```
idTx, payload = payload[:2], payload[config.tx_cnt:] # config.tx_cnt contiene el tamaño de bytes a recortar.
```

Pues resulta que hasta 127 (segundo byte, el primero siempre será 01 en este caso), `idTx` da lo siguiente:

```
...
b'017d' # 125
b'017e' # 126
b'017f' # 127
```

Pero a partir de 128 paso a tener lo siguiente en `idTx`:

```
b'018001' # 128
b'018101' # 129
```

¿Porqué empieza a coger un byte más? Me doy cuenta que el 128 es 2^7, pero no entiendo porque sucede esto. Dar soluciones parche se me ocurren varias, cómo puede ser solo trabajar de 1 a 127, o en la parte de decodificación de la trama a partir de 128 añadir un byte más. Pero lo que me gustaría saber es porqué sucede esto, si entiendo que un byte irá de 0 a 255.

---

A raíz de los comentarios hago un añadido.

Mi trama surge de convertir valores de tipo entero y *float* a byte. Para ello uso la librería `struct` de la siguiente manera:

```
payload = ustruct.pack('B', 1) + ustruct.pack('B', idTx)
for i in values:
    payload = payload + ustruct.pack('f', float(i))
```

Me parece que el motivo de verlo así sin el `\x` es porque al imprimir por pantalla no podía observar los datos correctamente, incluso cree una [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/430422/caracteres-no-se-muestran-con-buena-codificaci%C3%B3n?noredirect=1#comment768347_430422) para entender el motivo. Aunque no me mata la solución, al final lo solucioné empleando `binascii.hexlify()`, concretamente lo muestro así:

```
print('\t\t\tIDTX >> ',ubinascii.hexlify(idTx))
```

*NOTA: Es `ubinascii` y `ustruct` porque empleo MicroPython, pero no difiere del Python "normal".*

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Yo lo que no veo sentido es que digas que los dos primeros bytes son `b'017d'`. En realidad son 4 bytes. ¿No falta algún _escape_ tipo  `\x017d` que explicaría mucho de lo que pasa?

Comment: Coincido con @ChemaCortes. Algo está mal en la pregunta. Aunque tus cadenas tienen una `b` delante, sus contenidos no son "binarios", sino meras secuencias ascii (que casualmente representan datos en hexadecimal). Si dices que los dos primeros bytes de `payload` son por ejemplo 017d, entonces `payload` debería comenzar por `b'\x01\x7d'` y no por `b'017d'`. Pero por otro lado sí tienes bien lo de `payload[:2]` puesto que si la cadena fuera como pones en la pregunta los dos primeros "bytes" serían en realidad cuatro caracteres y se extraerían con `payload[:4]`. Entonces? Puedes revisarlo?

Comment: @ChemaCortes Muchas gracias a ambos por contestar, he añadido al final un texto que creo responde a vuestras dudas. :)

Comment: @abulafia A lo que comentas de que debería hacerse `payload[:4]` es algo que yo también pensé, pero luego vi que con un 2 funcionaba y entendí que era yo que debía estar equivocado

Comment: Creo que intuyo por dónde va el problema. Intenta cambiar el orden de `01` y  `128` cuando empaquetas el _payload_ a ver qué pasa.

Comment: @ChemaCortes no estoy seguro de entenderte. Que mi primer byte sea el segundo y que el segundo sea el primero? En que afecta eso?

Comment: En el modo de empaquetar. No estás trabajando con bytes, sino con estructuras C.

Comment: ¿Y con que trabajo? Hasta donde yo se `struct` genera un byte del valor, ¿no?

Comment: Ese es justo el problema, que cuando empaquetas un `unsigned char` (`'B'`) tiene que coincidir con el alineamiento de bytes que usa C, por lo que ocupar más de un byte. Vamos, que no puedes sumar dos `unsigned chars` con struct, tienes que empaquetarlos juntos (`struct.pack('BB', 1, 128)`). Que conste que no lo he probado.

Answer (score 0):

Esto no es una respuesta propiamente dicha, sino más bien una petición de aclaración. Debería ir en un comentario, pero ya que incluye código y es un poco extensa no es adecuada para comentario tampoco. Lo pongo de momento como respuesta y quizás acabe siendo una respuesta propiamente dicha. Y si no ya la borro.

Para que yo me aclare, tu `payload` lo estás creando básicamente con algo como lo siguiente:

```
i = 125  # Por ejemplo
payload = ustruct.pack('B', 1) + ustruct.pack('B', i)
for j in range(20):
    payload = payload + ustruct.pack('f', float(j))
```

Eso hace que `payload` sea verdaderamente un bytestring que si mostramos tal cual, sin hexlifys de por medio, se vería así:

```
b'\x01}\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00@@... etc'
```

En este caso sí tiene sentido lo que se plantea en la pregunta de separar los dos primeros bytes con una instrucción como la siguiente:

```
idTx, payload = payload[:2], payload[2:]
```

En este caso `idTx` tendrá siempre 2 bytes. No tiene sentido que sean 3 en ningún caso, pues `payload[:2]` son 2 bytes. En el ejemplo particular antes mostrado esos dos bytes serían, si se muestran tal cual:

```
b'\x01}'
```

La `}` es la interpretación como ASCII del segundo byte, que vale 125 en este ejemplo. Y si los pasas por `hexlify()` se verían como `b'017d'`

Revisa si tu código está haciendo algo diferente al mío, ya que como digo `payload[:2]` **necesariamente** son dos bytes siempre.

Y como demostración, repito el código anterior con varios valores de `i` que "atraviesan" la frontera del 128, para que se vea que siguen siendo dos bytes:

```
for i in range(125, 130):
  payload = ustruct.pack('B', 1) + ustruct.pack('B', i)
  for j in range(20):
      payload = payload + ustruct.pack('f', float(j))

  idTx, payload = payload[:2], payload[2:]
  print(hexlify(idTx), idTx)
```

Resultado:

```
b'017d' b'\x01}'
b'017e' b'\x01~'
b'017f' b'\x01\x7f'
b'0180' b'\x01\x80'
b'0181' b'\x01\x81'
```